# TRAC + SVN Check the TRAC Ticket Version before commit

Tags: svn, trac, pre-commit-hook

I am using SVN with the bug tracking tool "TRAC". 
I have three branches in SVN say, Branch_1.0, Branch_2.0, Branch_3.0. When QA raise bugs in TRAC they will mention the versions in TRAC as 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 respectively. Is it possible to configure SVN & Hudson in such as way that checkin should be allowed in each branch only if the corresponding TRAC ID mentioned in the SVN log matches the TRAC Version.

As for Now Trac is checking only one condition, whether the ticket mentioned is open. I would like to check whether the version of the ticket is matching with the svn Branch. Any help is appreciated.

Note: There is only one repository for SVN and TRAC

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more difficult, but it can be done.  One option is to use the [XML RPC plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) to give you an easily scriptable interface to the ticket system.  One of the RPC functions you can call is `ticket.getTicketFields()`, which will return an array containing all of the fields associated with a ticket.  You can use this to retrieve the version listed on a ticket, and then check that against the branch being used.  You would need to code up some way to map a ticket's 'version' field to a branch name (which you would extract from the first argument passed to Subversion's pre-commit hook script).